# cocos2dx: Sprite3D rotating, culling error

Tags: cocos2d-x-3.0

Hi I'm trying to have 2 sprites with different z in 3d world and a camera that rotates around the center of the screen and points at the center of the screen.
Even if the sprites has different z (and zorder, I don't know if this is necessary) the sprites are always visualized while I'm expecting to have the second sprite hided from the other...

This is helloworld layer init

```
    auto sp3d = Sprite3D::create();
sp3d->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2);
addChild(sp3d);

auto sprite = Sprite::create("JP9_table.png");
auto spritePos = Vec3(0,0,0);
sprite->setScale(0.3);
sprite->setPosition3D(spritePos);
sp3d->addChild(sprite,0);

auto sprite2 = Sprite::create("JP9_logo_yc.png");
auto spritePos2 = Vec3(0,0,10);
sprite2->setPosition3D(spritePos2);
sp3d->addChild(sprite2,10);
sp3d->setCullFace(GL_BACK);
sp3d->setCullFaceEnabled(true);
this->setCameraMask((unsigned short)CameraFlag::USER2, true);

camera = Camera::createPerspective(60, (float)visibleSize.width/visibleSize.height, 1.0, 1000);
camera->setCameraFlag(CameraFlag::USER2);
camera->setPosition3D(spritePos + Vec3(-200,0,800));
camera->lookAt(spritePos, Vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0));
this->addChild(camera);

this->scheduleUpdate();
angle=0;
```

and this is update:

```
 void TestScene::update(float dt)
{
    angle+=0.1;
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
    Vec3 spritePos=Vec3(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2,0);

    camera->setPosition3D(Vec3(visibleSize.width/2,visibleSize.height/2,0) + Vec3(800*cos(angle),0,800*sin(angle)));
    camera->lookAt(spritePos, Vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0));

}
```

I have tryed something simplier:

```
    auto sp3d = Sprite3D::create();
sp3d->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2, visibleSize.height/2);
addChild(sp3d);

auto sprite = Sprite::create("JP9_table.png");
auto spritePos = Vec3(0,0,0);
sprite->setScale(0.3);
sprite->setPosition3D(spritePos);
sp3d->addChild(sprite,0);

auto sprite2 = Sprite::create("JP9_logo_yc.png");
auto spritePos2 = Vec3(0,0,10);
sprite2->setPosition3D(spritePos2);
sp3d->addChild(sprite2,10);
sp3d->setCullFace(GL_BACK);
sp3d->setCullFaceEnabled(true);
```

even with `sp3d->runAction(RotateTo::create(20,vec3(0,3000,0)))` same error.
Is it a cocos2dx bug?

the sprite with z=10 disappear before it is covered by the other sprite...
remain hidden for a while, and when it should be hidden completely reappear!!!
Do I have forgot something?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check this.

```
_camControlNode = Node::create();
_camControlNode->setNormalizedPosition(Vec2(.5,.5));
addChild(_camControlNode);

_camNode = Node::create();
_camNode->setPositionZ(Camera::getDefaultCamera()->getPosition3D().z);
_camControlNode->addChild(_camNode);

auto sp3d = Sprite3D::create();
sp3d->setPosition(s.width/2, s.height/2);
addChild(sp3d);

auto lship = Label::create();
lship->setString("Ship");
lship->setPosition(0, 20);
sp3d->addChild(lship);
```

and

```
_lis->onTouchMoved = [this](Touch* t, Event* e) {
        float dx = t->getDelta().x;
        Vec3 rot = _camControlNode->getRotation3D();
        rot.y += dx;
        _camControlNode->setRotation3D(rot);

        Vec3 worldPos;
        _camNode->getNodeToWorldTransform().getTranslation(&worldPos);

        Camera::getDefaultCamera()->setPosition3D(worldPos);
        Camera::getDefaultCamera()->lookAt(_camControlNode->getPosition3D());
    };
```